# Codables error with Alamofire "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I got the response from API by using Alamofire, That response is in the form of [String:Any], i am trying to convert that response into codable format it showing error "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data".

PLease find my following code and help to me.

```
func apiHandling(){
        Alamofire.request(catrgeryurl, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.value != nil{
                if let data = response.result.value as? [String:Any]{
                    if let myStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Mainsite.self, from: data) {
                        //do something with myStruct
                        print(myStruct)
                    } else {
                        //handle myStruct being nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSONDecoder` expects `Data` rather than a dictionary. That's what the error's telling you.

Replace `responseJSON` with `responseData` and this is the recommended syntax to handle the response.

```
func apiHandling(){
    Alamofire.request(catrgeryurl).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(Mainsite.self, from: data)
            } catch { print(error) }
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here  myStruct gives to the nil value.

Comment: That's another question and cannot be answered without knowledge about the JSON and the struct. Actually you should get an error, not `nil`.